# Trying to create an editable Pop-up box

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Still new to this and I've created an interesting problem for myself that I can't solve...

I am trying to design my own “pop-up” box that allows the user to edit an existing string. It is popped up when a button is pressed, displaying the string in an entry box. Once the user has edited the string (or not), he hits the “OK” button and it goes away and the script should now have the new string.

My approach is something like this:

On button press, create a toplevel window with three widgets:

- simple label “Edit string, press ok when done”;
- editable entry containing the predefined string;
- button “OK” that destroys the toplevel window when pressed.

I have sort of got that working but can't figure out how to get the edited string.

I realize my fundamental problem is I am not thinking  in “event-driven” terms. It seems like this should be easily doable but but I can't see the forest at this point.

What am I missing? Am I over complicating this?

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

# Create the Pop-up box
proc popUpEntry { labelString } {
  global myString

  puts "POP:myString = $myString"

  set top [toplevel .top]
  set labelPop [label $top.labelPop -text $labelString ]
  set entryPop [entry $top.entryPop -bg white -width 20 -textvar $myString ]
  set buttonPop [button $top.buttonPop -text "Ok" -command { destroy .top } ]

  pack $labelPop
  pack $entryPop
  pack $buttonPop
}

# Pop-up command
proc DoPop {} {
  global myString

  set popUpLabel "Edit string, press ok when done:"
  puts "Before: myString = $myString"  
  popUpEntry $popUpLabel
  puts "After: myString = $myString"
}

# Initalize
set myString "String at start"

# Pop-up button invokes the pop-up command
set buttonPop [button .buttonPop -width 10 -text "Pop" -command {DoPop} ]
pack $buttonPop

#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
set entryPop [entry $top.entryPop -bg white -width 20 -textvar $myString ]
```

you are setting the `entry` control's `-textvar` to the **contents** of the variable `myString`.

You should set it to be the variable itself by removing the `$` symbol:

```
set entryPop [entry $top.entryPop -bg white -width 20 -textvar myString ]
```

Comment: Ah. So obvious after the fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the -textvar $myString, the code will not work because the popUpEntry function will return immediately after the popup was created - before the user has got any chance to enter something new.

You have to wait for the popup to close. This can be done with another global variable in popUpEntry:

```
...
global popup_closed
...
set buttonPop [button $top.buttonPop -text "Ok" -command {
      set edit_ready 1 
      destroy .top
      }

...

set edit_ready 0
popUpEntry $popUpLabel
vwait edit_ready
```